# Eigenvalues and eigenvectors linear algebra conceptual questions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> 1. If $A$ is a square matrix and $P$ is an invertible matrix each of whose columns is an eigenvector of $A$, then: $P^{-1}AP$ is a diagonal matrix. True or false.

I am not sure of this question but I think that it must be could be false because if $P^{-1}AP = D$, then $AP = PD$, and wouldn't these yield different results?

> 2. Let $T: V \to V$ be a linear transformation and let $B$ be a basis for $V$. Then $T$ and $[T]B$ have the same eigenvalues, but may have different vectors. True or False

I believe this answer is true because $T$ relative to the basis $B$ for $V$ shouldn't have different eigenvalues than $T$ right?

> 3. A square matrix $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if for each eigenvalue $c$ of $A$ the algebraic multiplicity of $c$ is equal to the dimension of the eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to $c$. True or False.

I believe this answer to be true because if the multiplicity of $c$ is one, then there would be one eigenvector for $c$, and therefore the eigenspace of $A$ would have the same dimension as $c$ which is one correct?

> 4. The dimension of the eigenspace of a matrix $A$ corresponding to an eigenvalue $c$ is equal to the rank of $A - cI$. True or false

This one I am stumped on, I believe it is true but I am not sure

> 5. true or false. A square matrix $A$ is singular if and only if $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

I know that this is true if there is a determinant of $0$, but is it also for an eigenvalue? I believe it is but wanted to check.

Please answer any or all of these questions, any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  For 5., remember that the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1: The statement is true. As you said, $P^{-1}AP = D$ is equivalent to
$$
AP = PD.
$$
If $D$ is diagonal, then what is the relationship between the columns of $P$ and the columns of $PD$? What is the relationship between the columns of $P$ and the columns of $AP$?

Question 2: Indeed, the statement is true.

Question 3: Indeed, the statement is true. However, your justification for the statement doesn't make any sense.

Question 4: The statement is false. The eigenspace is the **nullspace** of $A - cI$, but the rank of $A - cI$ is the dimension of the **column space** of $A - cI$. For example, with $c = 1$ and the diagonal matrix
$$
A = \pmatrix{1\\&2\\&&3},
$$
we find that the rank of $A - cI$ is $2$, but the dimension of the associated eigenspace is $1$.

Question 5: Indeed, the statement is true.

Comment: Concerning what you write about question 4, saying two numbers are not equal because they are the dimension of two different vector spaces is not (fully) valid.  By that kind of reasoning, the row rank and column rank of $A$ are not equal because they are the dimensions of different vector spaces, but in fact those vector spaces have the same dimension and thus the row and column ranks *are* equal.  To genuinely show question 4 is "false", an actual counterexample should be provided.

Comment: @KCd Fair enough

Comment: For question 2: The eigenvalues are the same as well as the eigenvectors, but their representations in respect to the basis may differ.